# How to remove Similar Keys in Dictionary

Tags: vba, loops, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary with the following key value pairs.

Key/Value 1: Bob/Number
Key/Value 2: Bobby/Number

I'm trying to remove the key/value pair where the key (Bob) appears in part of another key (Bobby) and keep the latter.

I tried a nested loop and the Instr function to remove keys with names that appear in other keys. This method removed all the keys, as it eventually compared the key with itself.

Is there some method or function I can use to complete this task?

I'm not looking for anyone to provide code. I'm trying to address this conceptually.

---

I figured it out. I created a counter variable called similar words and removed the key when it exceeded two.

```vb
dict_keys = dict.key
For Each key In dict_keys
    Dim similar_words As Integer
    similar_words = 0
    For Each search_key In dict_keys
        If InStr(1, search_key, temp_key, 1) > 0 Then
            similar_words = similar_words + 1
            If similar_words > 1 Then
                dict.Remove (key)
            End If
        End If
    Next search_key
Next key
```

Comment: Also, I could maybe create an array of the keys with the .keys method and loop according to the position of the key element in the array. Not sure about this approach though

Comment: If you already tried some code it likely only needs a small tweak, so it would be easier for us if you posted it.  Basically, don't remove a key if it's equal to the value you're testing as a sub-key.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I figured it out and wrote the code in my original post. It's probably a pretty verbose way of dealing with it, but it works